# Create External Connection from Azure to client on-premises network

Tags: azure, windows-server-2016

I am new in Azure so i would like to know what is the best way to for below requirement:

I have an azure RDP server .
I have a client server (external company)

I need to create an RDP connection between my Azure Server and client server

What is the best approach here ? (vpn gateway, azure firewall?)

On my prem I was using cisco L3 device with routing to client network.

Regards

Comment: What research have you done and what have you tried?

Comment: Nothing yet. I was looking in Microsoft labs but Not sure which option is best

Comment: The answer is that it depends on your needs. This site expects that people with questions do some research before asking here. I suggest you do that research, and if you still have questions, edit this question here to improve it.

Answer (score 1):

There are to commonly used options for this:

Express Route: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-gb/azure/expressroute/expressroute-introduction

Site VPN/Gateway: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-gb/services/vpn-gateway/

Without knowing a LOT more (budget, network setup, eventual endgame/strategy, bandwidth requirements, security requirements, level of support required, SLAs and so much more) it is impossible to recommend one or the other - but these are the two big technologies in use that you should research.